# PowerBI SHAPE MAP: One map with multiple fields to choose from?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following data:

```
STATE    AMOUNT A   AMOUNT B    AMOUNT C
AK        675,350    366,887     518,517 
AK        349,603    534,085     679,422 
AL        636,761    563,821     670,827 
AL        496,658    245,159     288,269 
AL        357,326    337,567     285,557 
AR        475,413    648,412     664,545 
OK        383,729    446,712     333,242
```

Using a SHAPE MAP, is it possible to have one map show either AMOUNT A, AMOUNT B, or AMOUNT C based on a slicer with some code attached to it?

Or, would I have to use 3 different maps with AMOUNT A for one, AMOUNT B for another, and AMOUNT C for the third map?